# Cannot find "Create Unit Test" for ASP.NET5 in VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I am learning ASP.NET5 with MVC6 recently. When I try to test the functions, I could not find "Create Unit Test" on the right click menu, though I can see Run Test and Debug Test options. The class locates in a folder called App_Code in the website project.
[image]

Then I created a console application and write a function in Program.cs. When I right click the function, I can see the "Create Unit Test" option.

[image]

May I ask how I can test functions in ASP.NET 5 classes? Thank you. Any related tutorials or documents are welcome.

Comment: This should help: http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html

Comment: Thank you. It is working for me.